# Websocket client hanshake error 426 on upgrade

Tags: websocket

Reader's digest version:
First time writing a websocket client.  Java 1.8 using Eclipse.  While on my workplace internal network getting a handshake error exception and the websocket log information tells me:

```
< Session 1c61123c-aa5f-4e59-a49d-b5d3c77c0bbd [598 ms]: Received handshake response: 
< 426
< connection: Keep-Alive
< content-length: 29
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< date: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 16:40:04 GMT
< server: nginx

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
        at webSocketExample.WebsocketClientEndpoint.<init>(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:60)
```

Details:
When I am connected to my internal work network and try to make a websocket connection I initially get connected but then I am sending a TCP reset.  If I throw the code on my laptop and connect over a different network like my home Comcast connection the connection is made and I receive the initial data response from the server.  I then take my laptop and hook it up to my internal work network and I go back to getting the handshake error.

I have been unable to resolve it yet with my internal security team as we don't do websocket development here so the knowledge base is a little lacking.

I set my proxy prior to calling this routine from my main.  It has been verified that I am getting connected to the server but then I am sending a reset.  Here is the code I am executing:

```
    try {

        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();

        final SSLContextConfigurator defaultConfig = new SSLContextConfigurator();

        defaultConfig.retrieve(System.getProperties());
        SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngine = new SSLEngineConfigurator(defaultConfig, true, false, false);

        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.SSL_ENGINE_CONFIGURATOR, sslEngine);
        client.getProperties().put(ClientProperties.LOG_HTTP_UPGRADE, true);

        client.connectToServer(new Endpoint() {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig config) {
                session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage(String message) {
                        System.out.println(message);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, ClientEndpointConfig.Builder.create().build(),
                new URI("wss://api.sandbox.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I have read all the posts/questions/answers that I have been able to find but haven't come up with anything yet.  I am somewhat limited on what I can personally do on our network as we have pretty tight security but I can work with my security team to find answers if I get asked a question.

I would think it has to be internal to my work network and the proxy maybe but I haven't been able to resolve it.  Also, this is the last part of the log information from the connection and error reporting:

Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 170

```
0000: 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31   20 34 32 36 20 55 70 67  HTTP/1.1 426 Upg
0010: 72 61 64 65 20 52 65 71   75 69 72 65 64 0D 0A 44  rade Required..D
0020: 61 74 65 3A 20 4D 6F 6E   2C 20 31 32 20 4A 75 6E  ate: Mon, 12 Jun
0030: 20 32 30 31 37 20 31 36   3A 35 30 3A 32 35 20 47   2017 16:50:25 G
0040: 4D 54 0D 0A 53 65 72 76   65 72 3A 20 6E 67 69 6E  MT..Server: ngin
0050: 78 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 6E 65   63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 4B  x..Connection: K
0060: 65 65 70 2D 41 6C 69 76   65 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65  eep-Alive..Conte
0070: 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A   20 74 65 78 74 2F 70 6C  nt-Type: text/pl
0080: 61 69 6E 3B 20 63 68 61   72 73 65 74 3D 75 74 66  ain; charset=utf
0090: 2D 38 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74   65 6E 74 2D 4C 65 6E 67  -8..Content-Leng
00A0: 74 68 3A 20 32 39 0D 0A   0D 0A                    th: 29....
[Raw read (bb)]: length = 58
0000: 17 03 03 00 35 EC 0F C3   40 0D 18 B4 7B 53 C6 2D  ....5...@....S.-
0010: F5 83 29 72 15 51 AC 31   8F 86 52 C9 3C 98 BB F8  ..)r.Q.1..R.<...
0020: 94 4A D7 3A 6E 17 8C 75   9E 58 25 0B AE B5 2F 13  .J.:n..u.X%.../.
0030: 8C 44 29 94 2F 4A 46 18   C9 1A                    .D)./JF...
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 29
0000: 55 70 67 72 61 64 65 20   74 6F 20 57 65 62 53 6F  Upgrade to WebSo
0010: 63 6B 65 74 20 72 65 71   75 69 72 65 64           cket required
> Session 6f920826-4b05-47bd-8cad-212038ff9fad [86 ms]: Sending handshake request:
> GET wss://api.sandbox.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/BTCUSD
> Connection: Upgrade
> Host: api.sandbox.gemini.com
> Origin: api.sandbox.gemini.com
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: nkgv7uk/bPSKBiOz5T/Bdg==
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Upgrade: websocket

< Session 6f920826-4b05-47bd-8cad-212038ff9fad [600 ms]: Received handshake response: 
< 426
< connection: Keep-Alive
< content-length: 29
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< date: Mon, 12 Jun 2017 16:50:25 GMT
< server: nginx
```

If you got this far, thanks...

Adding sniffer information from my network team:
You establish a connection Pkt 263, which you are going through the proxy server, mcweb-a 170.137.249.117. Then you transmit data.  The reset is sent in Pkt 280.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onTSB.png)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this.  The issue was a problem with my proxy server.  We had to add the specific endpoint as being allowable so it would skip some of the security checks.